# Administrative boundaries for historical political entities?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical, politics

Similar to [Seeking administrative boundaries for various countries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/seeking-administrative-boundaries-for-various-countries), do you have any data sources for historical political entities, and their administrative sub-units?

Data from any continent, any period in time works.

Edit: Some examples of shapefiles I would like to have:

- Kingdom of France and its duchies & counties: [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_France#/media/File:Map_France_1030-fr.svg).
- The British Isles: [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwPVk72GLfY).
- List of states under the Holy Roman Empire: [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_in_the_Holy_Roman_Empire).

Comment: Please [edit] and describe *historical political entities*, preferably with examples of their subunits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### National GIS Resources

[NHGIS has historical data for the United States](https://www.nhgis.org/)
[Great Britain Historical Geographical Information System (GBHGIS)](http://www2.port.ac.uk/research/gbhgis/)
[The Great Britain Historical GIS (Main)](http://www.gbhgis.org)
[GBHGIS Data Access](http://visionofbritain.org.uk/data/)
[National Heritage List for England (NHLE) Listing Data](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/the-list/data-downloads/)
[The US  National Historical GIS](http://www.nhgis.org)
[The China  Historical GIS](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~chgis)
[Chinese Civilization in Time and Space](http://ccts.ascc.net)
[Taiwan History and Culture in Time and Space](http://thcts.ascc.net)
[The Belgian Historical GIS](http://www.hisgis.be)
[The Historical GIS for the Netherlands](http://nlgis.dans.knaw.nl)
[Historical GIS Germany](http://www.hgis-germany.de)
[Russian Historical GIS](http://www.ihst.ru/personal/imerz/bound/bounds.htm)
[Japan Historical GIS](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chgis/data/japan/)
[China Historical GIS](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chgis/)

### More Resources

[The Digital Atlas of Roman and Medieval Civilizations (DARMC)](https://darmc.harvard.edu/)
[Historical GIS Data resources listing via David Rumsey Map Center](https://library.stanford.edu/rumsey/map-research/historical-gis-data)
[Historical GIS Research Network](http://www.hgis.org.uk/resources.htm)
[HistoricalGIS.org via Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160303224314/http://www.historicalgis.org/)
[Pleiades - Digital Ancient World Historical Atlas](https://pleiades.stoa.org/)
[ORBIS: The Stanford Geospatial Network Model of the Roman World](http://orbis.stanford.edu/)
[CShapes - historical maps of state boundaries and capitals in the post-World War II period](http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes.html)
[European GIS-data-infrastructure on historical national and regional administrative boundaries and historical place names](https://censusmosaic.demog.berkeley.edu/data/historical-gis-files)
[Historical World Atlas Repository](https://github.com/interactivethings/historical-world-atlas/) has global data starting from 2000 BC.