# Looking for “old” Parish & County Boundary Data set for Queensland, Australia

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical, australia

The latest datasets from [QSpatial](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/) no longer contain the Parish & County info. It is no longer used in Queensland. I am doing some research into historical mining activities and this dataset would be very helpful, so I don't have to create my own :)

Does anyone have a copy of the 'old' Cadastral (DCDB) dataset that still contains the Parish & County columns?

Comment: "Historical" is a good keyword when searching for old data. This question looks helpful: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13428/19566, and also see search results for [geospatial] and historical: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeospatial%5D+historical