# Historical Poland GIS dataset

Tags: data-request, openstreetmap, poland

I am working on a project about Interwar Poland and I am struggling finding some of the necessary data, specifically ***roads in 1934***. I managed to find data about the Voivodeships in 1934 as well as the surrounding countries at the time; however, I cannot find any data related to roads or communications, in a broader sense.

Of course, it doesn't have to be necessarily 1934, but something around the years before WWII kicked off.

Is there any source you could point me towards? I don't care much about the format as long as it's editable in QGIS, so GeoJSON, Shapefile, Geopackage... Whatever works.

Comment: Have you looked at topo sheets or similar raster data? [For example here](https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/view/all/where/Poland/?sort=Pub_List_No_InitialSort). I am well aware of the limitations of the raster format, but I have found that in many cases it has the significant advantage of existing at all. Also check out [this other post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13428/administrative-boundaries-for-historical-political-entities), it might point you to somewhere useful.

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of. There is a [Mapster](http://igrek.amzp.pl/) source for old rasterized maps, where you can find 1:1000000 map of Poland http://igrek.amzp.pl/mapindex.php?cat=WIG1M&listtype=standard&listsort=sortoption1. I would assume georeferencing and manual vectorization would be the best option. On the other hand, how accurate has the data to be? As the roads not neccessary changes over time, I would start with current OSM data and remove all highways/speedways (which were build in last 20-30 years). The remaining set could be accurate enough to cover the roads from 1930's.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. As you have mentioned, for now I am leaning towards comparing old raster maps with the current OSM data; I believe, after all, that's the most accurate method.